# How to override a service provided by a contrib module?

Tags: 8, symfony-services

I need to override Validator class from Telephone Validations contrib module.
I tried the both static and dynamic methods described here:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceModifierInterface;
// @note: You only need Reference, if you want to change service arguments.
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

/**
 * Modifies the language manager service.
 */

class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    // Overrides language_manager class to test domain language negotiation.
    // Adds entity_type.manager service as an additional argument.
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('telephone_validation.validator');
    $definition->setClass('Drupal\mymodule\MyValidator');

    $definition->addArgument(new Reference('country_manager'));
  }

}
```

and also static:

```
services:
  telephone_validation.validator:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\MyValidator
    arguments: ['@country_manager']
```

but it the both methods do not work, Drupal still uses Validator class form oroginal module

Also I tried modified method described here:
https://github.com/RikdeBoer/service_overrider

```
class MyServiceProvider implements ServiceModifierInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    // Overrides language_manager class to test domain language negotiation.
    // Adds entity_type.manager service as an additional argument.
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('telephone_validation.validator');
    $definition->setClass('Drupal\mymodule\MyValidator');

    $definition->addArgument(new Reference('country_manager'));
  }

}
```

The result is the same: MyValidator class is not used instead of default Validator class.
So what I am doing wrong?

Comment: See the linked doc for the correct class name, try `MymoduleServiceProvider`.

Comment: thanks, I somehow skipped the description:  the name of this class is required to be a CamelCase version of your module's machine name followed by ServiceProvider

Answer (score 0):

The name of your Class must be **MyModuleServiceProvider**.
You can the documentation here: [Altering existing services, providing dynamic services](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services)

> Note that if you want this service alteration to be recognized
> automatically, ***the name of this class is required to be a PascalCase
> version of your module's machine name followed by ServiceProvider,*** it
> is required to be in your module's top-level namespace
> Drupal\your_module, and it must implement
> \Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceModifierInterface (which
> ServiceProviderBase does).

This must solve your issue.